# Ubuntu 20.04 set mouse wheel at Wacom Inuos Pro S

Tags: 20.04, gimp, wacom, mouse-wheel

I want to switch from Windows/Photoshop to Ubuntu/GIMP.
My problem is the "Wacom Intuos Pro S Finger touch". It works out of the box but I can't map the touch ring.

I need "ctrl + mouse wheel up" and "ctrl + mouse wheel down" at touch ring to rotate an zoom in GIMP.

But in Ubuntu Control Center I can't set the mouse wheel.
I tried:

```
$ xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos Pro S Finger touch" Button 7 "key ctrl AbsWUp"
```

but it doesn't worked.

Comment: I will appreciate for mapping tutorial for Wacom Intuos Pro M